# php scraping a meta itemprop tag

Tags: php, xpath, output, scrape

I'm testing out my scraping abilities, trying to output values from any sort of tags. Coming up against something I'm unsure how to work, which is contained in a meta itemprop tag.

The source code looks like this, where I'm trying to scrape and output -0.205, under the meta itemprop tag name "priceChangePercent". (see at bottom line). *the value there is random depending on the time of day.

```
 <meta itemprop="name" content="USDJPY Spot Exchange Rate" /> <meta     
itemprop="url" content="https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/USDJPY:CUR" />   
<meta itemprop="tickerSymbol" content="USDJPY" /> <meta  
itemprop="exchange" content="" /> <meta itemprop="price" content="111.95" 
/> <meta itemprop="priceChange" content="-0.23" /> <meta 
itemprop="priceChangePercent" content="-0.205" />
```

Currently in the code that is working, I'm identifying content like this:

```
$query = "//div[@class='change-container']";
```

Which works just fine.

What would I have to modify exactly? I've tried

```
$query = "//meta[@itemprop='priceChangePercent']";
```

No luck. This is coming from this url: https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/USDJPY:CUR

Thanks so much.

my full code:

```
<?php 

  // this is yearly u.s. stock data
$doc = new DOMDocument;

// We don't want to bother with white spaces
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

 $doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;

 $doc->loadHTMLFile('https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/USDJPY:CUR');

 $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "//meta[@itemprop='priceChangePercent']";

$entries = $xpath->query($query);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
echo trim($entry->textContent);  // use `trim` to eliminate spaces


}

?>
```

Comment: it might be trivial, but do double quotes work? Otherwise the xpath looks right.

Comment: Ha, typo? `itempromp` vs `itemprop` the _m_

Comment: Actually made the typo on here only, I tested it with right spelling. thanks for pointing that out though. edited post. @scuzzy I will the quotes

Comment: Xpath looks fine, see https://3v4l.org/Bo7Fg - the error most likely is somewhere else (not in the question so far).

Comment: @hakre thanks so much for that, good to know you're able to. i edited my post to show the full source code. Wonder if you're able to identify the issue there.

Comment: You could try with `//meta[@itemprop='priceChangePercent']/@content` that is querying the content attribute nodes of these meta elements. There is also the `DOMXpath::evalutate()` method, that should be more handy in your case, please check the docs.

Comment: `$result = trim($entry->getAttribute('content'));` is this any better? your code seems to be getting the text content of the meta tag, which has no content, only attributes.

Comment: @scuzzy thanks for that. hm no it didn't. I actually modified the source code in original post, not sure if that makes anything more clear as to why that doesn't work.

Comment: I just tried your full code locally, and with `echo trim($entry->getAttribute('content'));` I can see `-0.1515` from `<meta itemprop="priceChangePercent" content="-0.1515" />`

Comment: @scuzzy got it working with that change. wonderful! thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your code sample:

```
echo trim($entry->textContent);
```

I've modified it to become:

```
echo trim($entry->getAttribute('content'));
```

your code seems to be getting the text content of the meta tag, which has no text content of it's own, only attribute content.